# How can I get the difference between two times which are being given as decimal format

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the difference between two times . I have two variable in decimal datatype to store the both time value. for example

```
decimal intime = 57.30
decimal breaktime= 8.36
decimal nettime = intime - breaktime
```

The nettime value should be 48.54. ie,
57:30 - 8:36 = 48:54 will get in excel. How can I get the same result in C#  using the variable intime and breaktime.

Comment: Why are you using decimals instead of, say, `Timespan`s?

Comment: Looks self-inflicted, do use TimeSpan.  If TimeSpan.Parse() doesn't help then get the seconds with 100 * (intime - Decimal.Floor(intime)).

Comment: There are lots of options. However, it seems to me the easiest is to format the `decimal` values as `string` values, then use `DateTime.ParseExact()` with a format string of e.g. `"mm.ss"`. Having thus converted the `decimal` values to `DateTime` values, you can then subtract one from another conventionally. See duplicate for the parsing part. I will point out, that in Excel a decimal value represents a date/time where the integer portion is the number of _days_; your reference to Excel in the question only makes it _less_ clear, not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```cs
TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)intime).Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(intime * 100 - (int)intime * 100)) - TimeSpan.FromMinutes((int)breaktime).Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(breaktime * 100 - (int)breaktime * 100))
```

You could extract the `decimal` to `TimeSpan` conversion in a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static decimal SecondsToDecimal(decimal input)
{
    var whole = Math.Floor(input);
    return Math.Round(whole + ((input - whole) * (100.0M / 60)),2);
}

public static decimal DecimalToSeconds(decimal input)
{
    var whole = Math.Floor(input);
    return Math.Round(whole + ((input - whole) * (60.0M / 100)),2);
}

public static void Main()
{
    decimal intime = 57.30M;
    decimal breaktime= 8.36M;

    var nettime = SecondsToDecimal(intime) - SecondsToDecimal(breaktime);
    Console.WriteLine(DecimalToSeconds(nettime)); //produces 48.54
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/xYLBIs

Answer (score -1):

You could try with this:

```html
  public static int[] getMinAndSec(double i)
  {
    int t = (int) ( 100 * i);
    int min = t/100;
    int sec = (t%100);
    return new int[] {min, sec};
  }
  
  public static void getDifference() { 
    int[] A = getMinAndSec(intime);  
    int[] B = getMinAndSec(breaktime);

    if(A[1] >= B[1])
      nettime = A[0] - B[0] + (A[1] - B[1]) * 0.01;
    else
    {
      nettime = A[0] - B[0] - 1 + (60 - (A[1] + B[1] - 60)) * 0.01;
    } 
  }
```

It converts your decimal to seconds and milliseconds, and then substracts them according to their value to give you back a time where nothing goes over 60.